# Where to download and how to add opencv to my project c# winforms?

Tags: c#, winforms, opencv

I'm using Visual Studio 2022 Community and Winforms running on .NET 4.7.2 in the project.

I want to add the opencv to my project. I went to this page: https://opencv.org/blog/2022/12/29/opencv-4-7-0/

and downloaded the Win pack and extracted the zip file.

Then went to the folder `opencv/build/bin` and there is one file inside: `opencv_videoio_ffmpeg470_64.dll`

But when I'm doing in my project `Add > Reference > Browse` and try to add the file, I get ab error:

> The file....dll could not be added make sure valid assembly or com.

Then I tried to go to this page: https://github.com/opencv/opencv/releases
and downloaded the sdk file unzipped it but then there are many folders and I couldn't find any dll files.

I want to use opencv for image/video processing tasks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use Open CV functions from a Windows forms C# project then perhaps you need the C# Open CV wrapper library called **Emgu CV**. You can search for the Emgu CV library from the Nuget package manager window under the **Browse** tab. You will need to install the **Emgu.CV.windows.runtime** library and find a version that is less than **4.4.x.x** which is compatible with your .NET framework 4.7.2. Installing a later version that than will most likely throw an error that the package is not compatible with the framework.

Consult with Github Emgu CV documentation on the version to learn more about the constructors to use for loading an image into a **Image<Bgr, byte>** object which let's you call a variety of image processing functions on the image such as detecting edges and corners, detecting contours and drawing over specific sections of the image.

Answer (score 1):

Before you look into "Emgu", give OpenCVSharp a look.

https://github.com/shimat/opencvsharp

Emgu is more of its own library, with its own extensions and less-obvious mapping between that and OpenCV. It also had real trouble with maintenance in the past. For a long time it appeared to mostly be based on OpenCV's C API.

OpenCVSharp is more of a wrapper, so any knowledge of OpenCV translates better. You don't need to look into its specific documentation as much.

On github, OpenCVSharp is also a lot more popular than Emgu. Community isn't everything but it's important when you need help.